# Query to Retrieving Organizational Hierarchy from a MongoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

## Question

How can I **connect or link** two collections in MongoDB so that I can query parent children relationship?

### Data schema for collection *Node*

```js
{
  "_id": objectId,
  "_parentNode": objectId,
  "_organisation":objectId //Note: this index appears only in top layer
  "name": string
}
```

### Data schema for collection *Organisation*

```js
{
  "_id": objectId,
  "_parentOrg": objectId, // Node: this index won't appear in top layer
  "name": string
}
```

### Hierarchical relationship

Organisation(not include `_parentOrg`) > sub-Organisation > ... > bottom-Organisation > Node(`_organisation`) > sub-Node > ... > bottom Node

And Node connect with **bottom-Organisation** with index `_organisationId`.

### What I expected after query is

This should be the parent children relationship, IDK if query support multiple level nest(resursive). Then I can use algorithim to build a tree like datastructure for next task.

```js
[
 {
   "_id": objectId,
   "name": string,
   "children": [{objectId},{objectId},...] // list of 1 level down nodes.
},...
]
```